# C++ making sure there is absolutely no stdin buffering

Tags: c++, c, stream, buffer, stdin

In C++, is it possible to have absolutely **NO** buffering for the standard input?

In Linux, you have to first put the terminal you're using in non-canonical mode, via some screwing with the `termios` or the `ncurses` library.

And in Windows, you need to us the Windows-only `conio.h`.

Would it be possible to have a simple, cross-platform statement using nothing but standard C++ that made sure that absolutely *everything* that happened in the standard input happened in real time, and could be accessed in real time by my program?

this means: *not* waiting for a carriage return or newline to parse input, *not* attempting to process escape characters at all, *not* throwing a fit with non-printable characters, etc.

I need something like this:

```
setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

But the terminal waits for newlines or carriage-returns anyways.

Is there really no way to get absolutely raw keyboard input without an external library?

If someone could supply me with some sort of inline-assembly or raw C++ solution for this, that would be great.

Comment: Please choose one of C and C++ for this question. Also, terminal configuration is independet of stdio buffering.

Comment: And no, there is no truly portable way (which is why 100s of libraries exist for this purpose), not even assembly is going to help you. Seriously, what should assembly do?

Comment: Downvoted because there is no language called C/C++. Please choose at most one of C and C++ unless your question is specifically about the interaction of the two.

Comment: On some systems the terminal really *is* a terminal located thousands of miles away, and doing its own buffering. A programming language cannot do much about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have a simple, cross-platform statement using nothing but standard C/C++ code that solves your problem.  This is because you are not just concerned with buffering within the program, but also with buffering done by the runtime environment of the program, including the operating system.  Depending on the environment, your program may simply lack the ability to do this!

Specifically, I don't think the C and C++ standard libraries have such functionality.  I expect there are good reasons for this:  the details of I/O facilities vary so widely between operating systems, it is unclear how you would specify such a requirement in a well-defined, implementable way.

Note that buffering is something that can be added at any stage.  This is an issue with more general I/O to the filesystem:  at what point can you be *sure* that your file write has been pushed to disk?  Even if you issue an operating system command to `sync` your filesystem, it is up to the firmware in your storage device to flush its buffers in a timely fashion...

Comment: There is also no guarantee your program has access to a standard input with this capability.